# TypeError: __add__() missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python

please help me out with this error

code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
    def __add__(self,other,other1):
        h1=self.a+other.a+other1.a
        h2=self.b+other.b+other1.b
        h3=self.c+other.c+other1.c
        return A(h1,h2,h3)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.a,self.b,self.c)
c1=A(4,5,6)
c2=A(1,6,4)
c3=A(7,8,3)
c=c1+c2+c3
print(c)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Affan/Desktop/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    c=c1+c2+c3
TypeError: __add__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other1
```

what should I do to get rid of this error

Comment: Shouldn't `add` have two arguments: `def __add__(self,other)`? Or what's the `other1`?

Comment: The operator uses only self and another object to calculate the result.

Comment: Why does `__add__` take two non-self arguments? What are the semantics you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__add__` only takes two arguments, and when you call `c1+c2+c3` it actually calls `add(add(c1,c2),c3)` if I'm not mistaken. As such, try

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
    def __add__(self,other):
        h1=self.a+other.a
        h2=self.b+other.b
        h3=self.c+other.c
        return A(h1,h2,h3)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.a,self.b,self.c)
c1=A(4,5,6)
c2=A(1,6,4)
c3=A(7,8,3)
c=c1+c2+c3
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    h1 = self.a + other.a
    h2 = self.b + other.b
    h3 = self.c + other.c
    
    return A(h1,h2,h3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The dunder methods have a specific signature that can be seen in the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

The reason that `a + b + c` is possible with only a binary (2 arguments) addition operator `+` is because it is evaluated left-to-right, as if the code was actually `(a + b) + c`

I haven't found any place in the python docs that explain the dunder methods in details, but it's easy to find a bunch of tutorials on the webz.